# Converting BPM From 12/8

Tags: time-signatures, beats

I have a new piece of music, and it has a part where it is 12/8 with dotted quarter notes being at 128  bpm. I was wondering what the quarter note tempo would be. And one last thing would it be counted
123 223 323 423?

Answer (score 3):

Dotted-quarter = 128bpm means "there are 128 dotted quarter-notes per minute".

A dotted quarter-note is equivalent to three eighth notes. Thus, dotted-quarter = 128bpm is equivalent to eighth-note = 128*3bpm = 384bpm.

A quarter-note is equivalent to two eighth notes. Thus, eighth-note = 384bpm is equivalent to quarter-note = 192bpm.

---

The proposed method of counting 12/8 time is fine.

Comment: So if I am reading this correct the quarter note bpm would be 192?

Comment: Another question would be is a dotted quarter be equivalent to one beat in 12/8?

Comment: @Jakub Yes, your reading is correct, but can you elaborate on the issue of whether or not the dotted quarter is one beat?

Comment: Are you trying to line this up with a sequencer which nominally counts in quarter notes?   A click that comes every 2/3 of a beat won't be very useful!  Better to keep the beat at 128 and think  triplets in 4/4 rather than 8ths in 12/8.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - Notably, the Play Panel in Musescore still displays BPM for quarter notes regardless of whether BPM for any other note value would make more sense.

Comment: So it does!   The click knows about compound time but the mm mark doesn't.    That needs fixing!   Actually, on closer investigation, the Play Panel doesn't seem to display the actual tempo at all.   Add a q.=80 mm mark to the score, playback and click notices, the tempo readout doesn't.  Seems to be indicating 'percentage of what's scored', like the Transport Bar slider in Sibelius.  The numeric readout is misleading.